# CodenameOne - ObjectiveC Bridge - is info.plist required?

Tags: codenameone

Looking at the Honeywell Captuvo SDK guide it mentions that before the SDK is called the info.plist file should include com.honeywell.scansled.protocol.decoder, com.honeywell.scansled.protocol.msr, and com.honeywell.scansled.protocol.pm

As I am using the ObjectiveC Bridge, how do I do this/do I need to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be referring to this:

> Connect to a Honeywell Captuvo Sled using Xamarin.iOS. Make sure you
>   have the following in your info.plist, otherwise the accessory will
>   not work.

```
<key>UISupportedExternalAccessoryProtocols</key> 
<array>     
  <string>com.honeywell.scansled.protocol.decoder</string>  
  <string>com.honeywell.scansled.protocol.msr</string>  
  <string>com.honeywell.scansled.protocol.pm</string> 
</array>
```

You can add information to the Codename One plist by using the build hint `ios.plistInject` in the build hints section:

```
ios.plistInject=<key>UISupportedExternalAccessoryProtocols</key> <array><string>com.honeywell.scansled.protocol.decoder</string><string>com.honeywell.scansled.protocol.msr</string><string>com.honeywell.scansled.protocol.pm</string></array>
```